# Приведение строки к нижнему регистру

Tags: c, строки

Как на Си привести строку, состоящую из русских символов, к нижнему регистру? Использовать windows.h нельзя

Comment: Это зависит от того, в какой кодировке строка. Например, строка задается строковым литералом `const char *string = "Мама Милу била битой"` в файле с исходным кодом. Если этот файл сохранен в utf-8, то и строка будет закодирована в utf-8, если файл в cp-1251, то и со строкой будет так же. Способы перевода в нижний регистр без использования стандартных библиотечных функций - разные.

Comment: Для кодировки `cp1251` посмотрите на [таблицу кодов символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). Обратите внимание на одинаковое расстояние между символами в верхнем и нижнем регистре (за исключением `ёЁ` (впрочем, их давно пора запретить -))

Comment: @avp, в cp886 был ещё один разрыв внутри.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, я же специально говорю о `cp-1251` (кстати, подойдет и `iso-8859-5`)

Comment: @avp, но это не мешает виндовой консоли работать в cp886...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да. В общем случае надо использовать таблицы преобразования.

Comment: а с99 MS всё ещё не умеет? можно было бы просто прочитать строку в `wchar_t` и просто пройтись по ней `towupper()`... должно  корректно работать для любой локали...